# Finding the number of distinct pairs of integers that sum up to an integer

Tags: java, hash, count, combinations

I am trying to count the numbers of pairs in an array such that each pair gives the sum of an integer!

I used the following code :

```
    public static int SumPairs(Integer []input, int k){
    Map<Integer, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int tmp=0;
    //System.out.println(pairs.toString());
     for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
     if(pairs.containsKey(input[i])){
            System.out.println(pairs.containsKey(input[i]));
             System.out.println(input[i] +", "+ pairs.get(input[i]));
             input[i]=0; 
            tmp++;      

        }

        else
            pairs.put(k-input[i], input[i]);
    }return tmp;
}
```

the problem is ; for example when my array is `1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4` 
and  `sum = 5` 
it compute as following

```
(4,1)
(4,1)
(4,1)
(3,2)
```

I want to prevent the method from using a number more than once !!
so the output will be

```
(4,1)
(3,2)
```

Comment: Is the input array guaranteed to be sorted in ascending order where the difference between an element and it's predecessor is never greater than one (your example array suggests so)?

Comment: Normally no , the array could be in any order, should I sort it first?

Comment: If the input is unsorted, it should stay unsorted. It would otherwise increase the runtime complexity. I just asked, because it would have simplified the problem.

Comment: Mmmm thanks , please let me know if you find the solution

Comment: I reworked my answer using sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a map storing values and their frequencies:

```
public static int SumPairs(Integer[] input, int k){
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    int pairsCount = 0;      

    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        int value = input[i];
        int complement = k - input[i];

        if(frequencies.containsKey(complement)){                
            int freq = frequencies.get(complement) - 1;
            pairsCount++;
            //System.out.println(value + ", " + complement);    
            if(freq == 0){
                frequencies.remove(complement);
            }else{
                frequencies.put(complement, freq);
            }
        }else{
            if(frequencies.containsKey(value)){         
                frequencies.put(value, frequencies.get(value) + 1);             
            }else{
                frequencies.put(value, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return pairsCount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately it's still not work:(

Comment: Have you thought of cases such that {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4} sum = 8

Comment: @raghadAlamri What should be the answer to {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4} sum = 8? I thought 1 -> pair (4, 4). Do you mean it should return 7 in that case?

Comment: @Calculator the answer to {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4} sum = 8 should be 1, solution being (4,4).

Comment: Fails for:
k = 8, arr = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4];
k = 7, arr = [1, 5, 66, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 2, 5];
k = 2, arr = [1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can help

```
def numberOfPairs(a, k):

    # Let's do a o(n) approach by maintaining all the compliments of the K in a 
    # visited set

    compliments = set()
    result = set()
    for v in a:
        # See if the element is in the compliments set, if so thats the pair
        if v in compliments:
            result.add((v, k-v))
        # If the element is not found in visited save the compliment of it in the visited set    
        else:
            compliments.add(k-v)
    


    return len(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for all the test cases I could think of. Please add in the comment section any test case that this code fails so that I can fix it. If it works, please accept the solution.

```
public class DistinctPairs {

    private static int count(int target, int... arr) {
        int count = 0;
        Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int k = target - arr[i];
            int[] pair = new int[]{k, arr[i]};
            Arrays.sort(pair);
            String s = Arrays.toString(pair);
            if (set.contains(k) && !seen.contains(s)) {
                count++;
                seen.add(s);
                // uncomment this print statement to print the distinct pairs
                // System.out.println(s);
            } else {
                set.add(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    // test suite and driver method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(count(10, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1) == 3);
        System.out.println(count(47, 6, 1, 3, 46, 1, 3, 9) == 1);
        System.out.println(count(9, 3, 2, 1, 45, 27, 6, 78, 9, 0) == 2);
        System.out.println(count(9, 3, 3, 2, 1, 45, 27, 6, 78, 9, 0) == 2);
        System.out.println(count(6, 1, 5, 7, -1) == 2);
        System.out.println(count(6, 1, 5, 7, -1, 5) == 2);
        System.out.println(count(2, 1, 1, 1, 1) == 1);
        System.out.println(count(5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4) == 2);
        System.out.println(count(8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4) == 1);
        System.out.println(count(7, 1, 5, 66, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 2, 5) == 3);
        System.out.println(count(5) == 0);            
        System.out.println(count(5, 1) == 0);
        System.out.println(count(7, 3, 4) == 1);
    }
}
```

Another approach can be to follow the classic solution of Two Sum Problem and add the pairs in a set as you find them, all this in the same pass. This set will be of a custom wrapper class with arr[i] and (target - arr[i]) as it's members and you'll need to override hashcode() and equals() methods in such a way that (a,b) is the same as (b,a). At the end simply return the size of the set. This approach will have the same time and space complexity in Big-O terms as the first approach.

```
int count(int target, int... nums) {
    Set<Pair> uniPairs = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int diff = target - nums[i];
        if (seen.contains(diff)) {
            Pair pair = new Pair(nums[i], diff);
            uniPairs.add(pair);
        }
        seen.add(nums[i]);
    }
    return uniPairs.size();
}

class Pair {
    int a;
    int b;
    public Pair (int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Pair pair2 = (Pair) obj;
        return ((a == pair2.a) && (b == pair2.b)) || ((b == pair2.a) && (a == pair2.b));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(a, b) + Objects.hash(b, a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sumPairs(Integer[] input, int sum){
    List<Integer> complementaries = new ArrayList<>(input.length);
    int pairs = 0;
    for(Integer number : input){
        if(complementaries.contains(number)){
            complementaries.remove(number);
            pairs++;
        }
        else{
            complementaries.add(sum-number);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Now it should work perfectly.

The complementaries array is used just for keeping track of the numbers needed for making the sum. If it contains the number it means that we iterated over its complementary before, so we can just add one pair and remove the number from the list of complementaries. Oherwise we add the complementary of the current number to the list without incresing the pairs counter.

Comment: Sorry it does not work, I still get wrong answers :(

Comment: Fails for:
sum = 2, input = [1,1,1,1]; sum = 8, input = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
and infinitely similar test cases.

Answer (score 0):

> The code takes an array and returns all possible pairs that have sum as specified. As the question asks to print **number of pairs** and not the pairs, the length of array divided by 2 would give the desired answer.

```
int notInArray(float a[],float m,int n)
{
   int i,j,k;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       if(a[i] == m)
           return 0;
   }
   return 1;


}
int main() {

   int i,j,k;
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);   //Input the number of elements in array.

   float arr[n];

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       scanf("%f",&arr[i]);   //input the array elements


   float copyArr = arr[0];

   float m;

   if (n == 0)
       return 0;

   scanf("%f",&m);   //input the sum

   float resArr[n];
   int b;
   int a=b=0;

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
       {
           if(arr[i]+arr[j]==m && notInArray(resArr,arr[i],n))
           {
               resArr[a++] = arr[i];
               resArr[a++] = arr[j];

               //printf("%.0f %.0f\n",arr[i],arr[j]);
           }
       }
   }

   printf("All possible pairs: \n");
   for(i = 0;i<a;i+=2)
       printf("%.0f %.0f\n",resArr[i],resArr[i+1]);

   int len = (int)( sizeof(resArr) / sizeof(resArr[0]) )
   printf("Number of such pairs: %d",len);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void distinctPairs(int[] arr, int k){
    int length = arr.length;
    int count = 0;
    Map<Integer,Integer> pairs = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++){
            if(arr[i]+arr[j] == k ){
                if(!(pairs.containsKey(arr[j])&&pairs.containsValue(arr[i]))) 
                pairs.put(arr[i], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    count = pairs.size();
    System.out.println("Pairs are "+pairs+"  count  = "+count);
}
```

This works for me. Steps I followed.

1. Check if sum of a pair is equal to required(k).
2. Check if the pair doesn't already exist in the map.

Comment: It works but time complexity is O(n²) and space complexity is O(n). It's possible to do it in linear time and space.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the hashmap to store all values of the array. Then iterate over the array and check if the map contains (K - a[i] ). If the map contains then increment count and remove both keys from the map.

```
private int getDistinctPair(int k,int[] input){
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int pairs = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length-1; i++) {
            map.put(input[i], input[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <input.length-1 ; i++) {
            int diff = k - input[i];
            if(map.containsKey(diff)){
                pairs++;
                map.remove(diff);
                map.remove(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return  pairs;
    }
```

Comment: Fails for 
k = 9, arr = [3, 2, 1, 45, 27, 6, 78, 9, 0];
k = 9, arr = [3, 3, 2, 1, 45, 27, 6, 78, 9, 0];
k = 6, arr = [1, 5, 7, -1]

Apparently, your code is handling only positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can slove by using below code:

```
def countPairs(arr, k):
    possible_maps = []

    for num in arr:
        pair_matches = list(filter(lambda n: n + num == k, arr))

        if len(pair_matches) > 0:
            possible_maps += list(map(lambda nm: (num, nm), pair_matches))

    return len(set(map(lambda pair: ','.join(str(n) for n in sorted(pair)), possible_maps)))
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

My C# way to do this in a single loop with just another list to store temporary diff values.

```
        private static int SumPairs(int[] arr, int sum)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> frequency = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            List<int> temp = new List<int>();
            int count = 0;

            foreach (int i in arr)
            {
                int diff = sum - i;

                if (!frequency.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    if (temp.Contains(i))
                    {
                        frequency.Add(i, diff);
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp.Add(diff);
                    }
                }
            };

            return count;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

my C# implementation using `Tuple`

```
static List<Tuple<int,int>> GetUniquePairs(int[] arr, int sum)
        {
            Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> kvp = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();
            List<Tuple<int,int>> result = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
            int length = arr.Length;
            for(int i = 0;i < length; i++)
            {
                int j = i + 1;
                while (j < length)
                {
                    if(arr[i]+arr[j] == sum)
                    {
                        Tuple<int, int> key = new Tuple<int, int>(arr[i], arr[j]);
                        if (!kvp.ContainsKey(key))
                            kvp.Add(key, 1);
                    }

                    j++;
                }
            }

            var keys = kvp.Keys;
            foreach(var k in keys)
            {
                result.Add(k);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The Simplest Solution of your problem of finding distinct pair:

```
public static int SumPairs(int[] input, int k) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int data : input) {
        if (pairs.containsKey(k - data) && pairs.get(k - data) == 0) {
            tmp++;
            pairs.put((k - data), pairs.get(k - data) + 1);
        } else if (!pairs.containsKey(data)) {
            pairs.put(data, 0);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

It has been tested for **1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 and sum = 5**. Also for **4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 and sum = 8**. 
If any confusion feel free to ask me. Cheers.

Comment: This is wrong!! I got 0 for test input {1,5,66,2,3,4,7,0,2,5}

Comment: What's your value of k?

Comment: My value is 7 for k. Check it. The answer you gave is wrong.

Comment: Dear, I got the output  = 4... Can u please give your process of testing..

Comment: use the following code in main method...........    int input[]={1,5,66,2,3,4,7,0,2,5};
  int k = 7;
  System.out.println("Total distinct Pair: " + SumPairs(input, k));

Comment: @Md.AshikAliKhan Your solution gives answer for arr = [1,5,66,2,3,4,7,0,2,5] and k = 7 as 4. These are the pairs it considers --> (5, 2), (3, 4), (7, 0), (2, 5)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class DistinctPairs {     
   static int numberOfPairs(int[] arr,int k)
   {
       HashSet<String> s=new HashSet<String>();
       int n=arr.length;
       int sum=0;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
           {
               sum=arr[i]+arr[j];
               if(i==j)
               {
                   continue;
               }
               else
               {
                  if(sum==k)
                  {
                      String l=String.valueOf("("+arr[i]+","+arr[j]+")");
                      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(l);
                      String rl=sb.reverse().toString();
                      if(s.add(l)==false)
                      {

                      }

                  }
               }

           }
       }
        System.out.println(s.toString());

       return s.size()/2;
   }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int b[]={1,5,66,2,3,4,7,0,2,5};
     int size=numberOfPairs(b,5);  
     System.out.println(size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails for: sum = 2, input = [1,1,1,1];
sum = 8, input = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] and infinitely similar test cases.